# How to create a hibernate.properties file at runtime in Tomcat

Tags: java, hibernate, tomcat

I've got a web app that makes use of a servlet included in a jar provided by a 3rd party. The servlet uses hibernate.properties to configure dB settings required to talk to a DB.

This is problematic for us because this file must be different for each environment. I have tried creating a template file and generating the real file at context start up.

The file generation works, however the app doesn't find the file after creating it. If I restart tomcat the app works because the file already exists from the last time it was started.

I'm not sure whether I'm fighting java or Tomcat on this one, but I'd like to know why it can't find newly created files on the classpath.

I've also been searching for the hibernate code that actually loads this file and can't spot it. It's possible that seeing how it's loaded may give me some clues.

My file generator looks like:

```
public class HibernatePropertiesFileGenerator implements ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent>, ApplicationContextAware {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HibernatePropertiesFileGenerator.class);

    private ApplicationContext context;

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
        this.context = applicationContext;
    }

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(ContextRefreshedEvent event) {
        LOGGER.info("Generating hibernate.properties file.");
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
        configuration.setClassForTemplateLoading(this.getClass(), "/");
        configuration.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
        configuration.setIncompatibleImprovements(new Version(2, 3, 20));

        Map<String, Object> freemarkerDataModel = Collections.singletonMap("env", (Object) context.getEnvironment());

        try {
            URL url = this.getClass().getResource("/hibernate.properties.ftl");
            File templateFile = new File(url.getFile());
            File outputFile = new File(templateFile.getParentFile(), "hibernate.properties");
            Template template = configuration.getTemplate("hibernate.properties.ftl");
            FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(outputFile);
            template.process(freemarkerDataModel, fileWriter);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Unable to create hibernate.properties file.", e);
        }
        LOGGER.info("hibernate.properties file generated.");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generating the template wasn't working because hibernate actually reads hibernate.properties in a static class initialiser for org.hibernate.cfg.Environment. By the time my file was created this code had already run.

I've worked around this by templating the hibernate.cfg.xml file instead and ditching the hibernate.properties file.